# for loop in list index

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a simple yet difficult question for me, I am familiar with for loops in python but as I am trying to loop through a range in the list index it gives me an error.

```
for x in range(0,9):
    fakelist[f'{x}'].split('\n\n')
```

This code gives me a TypeError.

Comment: Why are you converting `x` to a string and using it as a list index? List indexes shound be ints

Comment: If you look at the stack trace returned by the type error, it will tell you where the `TypeError` occurs. Hint: it's not the for loop causing it.

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? 'fakelist', is it a dict ? If yes, the values of this dict,, are they strings ?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use something like this: `fakelist[x].split('\n\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `fakelist` is a `Python List datatype`

Your code is trying to pass a `string` datatype variable as index to the into the list - `fakelist` Hence the error.

```py
for x in range(0,9):
    print(type(f'{x}'))
    fakelist[f'{x}'].split('\n\n')
```

If you run the above code you can see that the `index` what you are trying to pass is a `string` type

Try to use the following instead.

```py
for x in range(0,9):
    fakelist[x].split('\n\n')
```